# Converting Kelvin into degree Celsius with CDO

Tags: netcdf, ubuntu, climate-data-operators

I am trying to convert Kelvin into Degree Celcius with cdo in Ubuntu. I am using this code: `cdo -addc,-273.15 <infile> <outfile>` and this one `cdo -setattribute,tas@units="degC" -addc,-273.15 <infile> <outfile>`
A new netCDF file is generated with the new unit degree Celsius but when I run the whole netCDF file the temperature is still shown in Kelvin. How can I do this?

Comment: can you post the header you get from "ncdump -h outfile" ?

Comment: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/1357 See this discussion. Generally, any support needed on CDO should be obtained from this forum, you will be more likely to get help